# How to call method of an object in immediate window?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
double calc_price (Shoes &shoe)
{
   double price;
   price = shoe.getPrice() * shoe.getNumber();
   return price;
}
```

The code above can run, but I want to find out what is shoe.getPrice(). I tried to add a breakpoint, and call shoe.getPrice() in immediate window in visual studio, but it says "CXX0039: Error: symbol is ambiguous".

According to Microsoft Doc, I added scope resolution,

```
Shoes::shoe.getPrice()
```

while it says CXX0017: Error: symbol "shoe" not found.

I only have the .h file for the class Shoes, the .cpp file is hidden.

So how can I output shoe.getPrice() except adding a temp variable.

---------------------------Edit---------------------------------------

Below is the declaration of class Shoes.

```
Class Shoes
{
public:
  Shoes();
  double getPrice();
  int getNumber();
private:
  double price;
  int number;
}
```

Comment: Is `calc_price` a member function of `Shoe`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. No. It is a separate function defined in main.cpp.

Comment: Then perhaps you want `getPrice(shoe)`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  getPrice(shoe) won't work, since getPrice() does not take any input. Though I tried, it says "CXX0017: Error: symbol "getPrice" not found"

Comment: Sorry I was mistaking get_price and calc_price. Anyway, `Shoes::shoe.getPrice()` is wrong, maybe you need `shoe.Shoes::getPrice()`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It still complains "CXX0039: Error: symbol is ambiguous". By the way, this is the first time I saw  an expression like this ` shoe.Shoes::getPrice() `, is there any doc I can refer to about this expression?

Comment: `shoe.Shoes::getPrice()` is normal [qualified member access](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup) (look for "Qualified name lookup can be used to access a class member that is hidden by a nested declaration...")

Comment: Could you provide the declaration of Shoes class ?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT I've added the declaration. I thought this may be related to immediate window itself. I use Matlab a lot, where I can input almost anything to command window. Maybe immediate window is less powerful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to get its value, but not in immediate window. In debug mode, at the top of "Autos" window, return value of the most recently called function is listed.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019

Go to the section "View return values of method calls"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).